# Does 7 card poker hand odds change if i know 2 of the cards? If so how?

Tags: texas-hold-em, probability

In Wikipedia, it shows that the Pair probability for 7-card poker hand is 43.8%.

After that 2 card is dealt to me, lets say Ace of Spades and 7 of Diamonds, does knowing these 2 cards effect the probability of Pair? If so how? If not, why?

Comment: Probability is a measure of certainty based on information, so yes, *every* piece of information you get changes the probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

## Intuition says yes...

For any random seven cards, there are 21 ways to combine them in forming a pair: pick one of them, then pick another, and divide the total count by 2 because you can change the order.

Knowing that your first two cards are *not* a pair, you have lost one of the potential ways to form at least one pair, reducing your chances by a small amount, since you only have 20 ways remaining to achieve it (see below for further explanation).

## ... and the math agrees.

The probability that you end up with no pairs at the end, with zero cards already in hand, is 135168/643195 or just under 21%.

Note that this means you get *at least* a pair in 79% of hands, but some of those hands are more than a pair (two pair, trips, quads, full house) and some without a pair are ranked higher (flush, straight).

With two cards in hand, and no pair yet, that increases to 8448/37835 or just over 22%.

The odds of getting no pair at all went up by 1.3% once you miss the first possible pair.

---

This reasoning applies to some extent with more cards being pulled, but other factors begin to grow and balance out, such as the likelihood that you match an existing in-hand card, which grows as you add more cards to the hand.

Comment: Are you counting flushes and straights as well?  Pair or better should be 82%+ of all 7 card combos?

Comment: Ranking of hands is irrelevant to the question, and therefore the answer. You can expect two or more cards of the same rank(s) in 79% of seven-card hands. I have no idea where you got 82% from.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  From the OP's 43.8, I assumed that higher-ranked hands should be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your figure of 43.8% for a pair means "chance for a hand that is worth exactly one pair".  So it excludes both better and worse hands.

Some hands with a pair in them aren't even counted here (for instance if the seven cards have a pair and a flush, it's just a flush).  But if you make the flush less likely, then some of those pairs that weren't counted before become "just a pair".

So the overall strength of your hands goes down (from 82% pair or better to only 80%), but the probability of a hand having exactly one pair goes up.

| Hands | one pair exactly | one pair or better |
| --- | --- | --- |
| All combinations 7 cards | 43.8% | 82.5% |
| A♠ 7⋄ hole cards | 45.8% | 80.5% |